# If I activate expose, then spaces, can I force the window arrangement to stay the same in both views?

Tags: window-manager, spaces, leopard, expose

This is on OS X 10.5.8 (Leopard).

Let's say I activated Expose (All Windows), and I see my windows in a certain arragement. Then I activate Spaces. The spaces I was in sometimes shows the windows in a different arrangement from what I saw with Expose alone. Use case: I want to move an obscured window from one Space to another. The current behavior makes this more difficult to locate the window I had my eye on. I'd like to always have the same arrangement in both Expose-alone and Expose-plus-Spaces.

UPDATE:
I noticed that the z-order of windows in the Space affects whether the issue occurs; that makes it even more annoying.

UPDATE 2:
Also, I found a non-ideal workaround: using the shift-[shortcut key] to slowly activate Spaces so I can more readily see where my window is going. This doesn't solve my problem because I normally use a screen corner to activate Spaces. If someone can tell me how I can use screen-cornering with the slow Spaces activation, that would qualify as an answer too.

UPDATE 3:
Another trick I forgot about that makes the issue bearable: while Exposé is active, pressing Option/Alt will display window titles - this works also if you activate Spaces while All Windows is active. That helps me locate the window faster.

Expose alone:
[image: expose alone]

Expose plus Spaces (of the same windows as Expose alone):
[image: expose plus spaces]

Comment: What OS X version are you on? Do you use any 3rd party Exposé software (if there even is any)? My windows (on 10.6.7, and was so also in 10.6.6) always get arranged into a neat grid when using Exposé ([see screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/1WJKC.png)) and the arrangement doesn't change after activating Spaces.

Comment: I'm on Leopard, 10.5.8. I haven't installed any Exposé or Spaces add ons (I don't know of any).

Comment: ah yes, I see now that Exposé was updated in Snow Leopard: http://www.apple.com/macosx/refinements/ which introduced the grid view. You wouldn't consider upgrading to Snow Leopard as an answer, would you.

Comment: @koiyu Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not willing to upgrade for a minor issue like this.